# Enabling two factor authentication in an iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-developer-program

I am a React Native Developer and I just purchased a Mac mini. I would like to start developing iOS apps but I don't own an iOS device. Apple's Developer website says that in order to enrol in Apple Developers Program, my Apple ID must have two-factor authentication enabled. I've signed in with the Apple ID in the iOS simulator provided by Xcode but I'm unable to turn on Two Factor Authentication in the simulator. Is there any way that I can enable Two Factor Authentication or get an Apple developer id without an Apple phone?

Comment: Realistically if you want to develop iOS apps you will need at least one iOS device. The simulator lets you perform most testing, but you should always run your app on a real device as well.

Comment: You don't need to enable 2FA on a simulator, you can enable it on your mac mini. @nano's answer is correct and should be marked as such. I had a similar situation while testing apple-sign-in and enabling 2FA on my mac did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Lately i had the same problem and they let me use my macbook pro as a device for 2 factor auth, take a look at [this](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/two-factor-authentication-3543274/)

> To set up 2FA on your Mac, go to System Preferences > iCloud > Account
>   Details. Log in using your Apple ID. Then select Security and Turn On
>   Two-Factor Authentication.
>
> Next you will be asked for a phone number - make sure this is active,
>   because Apple will text a number to it. Once you receive that number
>   you need to enter it on your Mac's verification screen.

Comment: The person asking the question specifically says they don't have an iOS device - how does this information answer the question?

Comment: Hi Cindy, i think they have the Mac mini, the first sentence in the question is "I am a React Native Developer and I just purchased a Mac mini" and i could use my MacBook Pro for the same development build so i think this solution is viable, to confirm 2FA you need a phone number, not an iPhone so i think this can work